# Convert the categorical values in a column into columns themselves (Transpose)

Tags: postgresql, pivot

Experts,

I have this data -

```
ID       |  buckets      | SUM (USD)|
--------- --------------- ---------
1        | 10 - 20       | 500      |
--------- --------------- ---------
1        | 30 - 40       | 100      |
--------- --------------- ---------
2        | 30 - 40       | 300      |
--------- --------------- ---------
```

Now the output that I'm trying and failing to get in PSQL when it is so easy in Excel ->

```
ID       |. 10-20        | 30-40    | Total_USD |
--------- --------------- ---------  -----------
1        |   500         |  100     |    600    |
--------- --------------- ---------  -----------
2        |               |  300     |    300    | 
--------- --------------- ---------  -----------
```

Would appreciate if you can guide me/ send me the right direction

Comment: I found some resources showing PIVOT might work - since in excel that is exactly what's working. BUT I can't install package/import since I have read only access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pivot (or crosstab) can be done using filtered aggregation:

```
select id, 
       sum("sum") filter (where buckets = '10 - 20') as "10 - 20",
       sum("sum") filter (where buckets = '30 - 40') as "30 - 40",
       sum("sum") as total
from the_table
group by id
order by id;
```

But in general, SQL isn't designed for this type of reporting. Doing that in Excel (or any other reporting software) is a much better solution.